# Tests are failing after Angular 2 RC5

Tags: testing, angular, migration

I had used the following format for my tests:

```js
export function main() {
    describe('Angular2 component test', function() {
         it('should initialize component',
           async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
              var template = '<specific-component-tag>';
                return tcb.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, template)
                .createAsync(TestComponent)
                .then((fixture) => {
                    expect(fixture.componentInstance.viewChild).toBeDefined();
                    fixture.detectChanges();
                    expect(fixture.componentInstance.viewChild.items.length).toBe(1);
                    // .... etc.
                }).catch (reason => {
                    console.log(reason);
                    return Promise.reject(reason);
                });
         })));
      });
}
```

This work fine in RC4. But RC5 came suddenly and now this code have not worked.
It throws me the following errors:

```js
Module ".... @angular/core/testing" has no exported member 'it'.
Module ".... @angular/core/testing" has no exported member 'describe'.
Module ".... @angular/core/testing" has no exported member 'expect'.
Module ".... @angular/core/testing" has no exported member 'beforeEachProviders'.
Module ".... @angular/compiler/testing" has no exported member 'TestComponentBuilder'.
Module ".... @angular/compiler/testing" has no exported member 'ComponentFixture'.
```

Please help me to migrate this test to angular2 RC5.

Update:
I have already read RC5 [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but nothing comes to my mind how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Jasmine imports available through @angular/core/testing are removed. So remove the imports for the following

Before:

```
import {
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

after

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/main/ambient/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
import {
  inject, addProviders
} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

The reference path should be the first line in the file and it should point to jasmine type definition file. (Update the relative up. i.e the ../../ to whatever)To get jasmine type defitions, add the following line to ambientDevDependencies. Mine looks something like this

```
{
  "ambientDevDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  },
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

Also change

```
  beforeEachProviders(() => [InMemoryDataService]);
```

to

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
describe('...', () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ InMemoryDataService ]
  });
  it(...);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need the *reference* include as jasmine should be picked up through the global typings.

Comment: @toepoke.co.uk Based on my project setup with angular-cli, compilation appears to fail till I reference it. The IDE (VsCode) also complained that it couldn't find referenes to describe, it etc..

Comment: @filoxo Can you please edit/update the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @filoxo Thanks for revising it :)

Comment: yay for collaboration! :D

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the 1st 'after' the import of `addProviders` is not existent for me in RC6, so I only removed it and everything worked. I haven't researched this enough though.

Comment: @edmundo096 From RC6, construct your test cases using TestBed. See the bottom of the answer for an example.

Comment: addProviders fails for me (aka Sublime says that @angular/core/testing/index has no exported member addProviders), I am on angular 2.1.1 in an Ionic setup; also, when running the test, I keep getting "No provider for MyService", although I have imported it, so not sure if that still works in 2.1.1 or if that is conditional on addProviders working...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at changelog:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

It looks like API, which you are using is deprecated - path and names has changed. :)

For example:

- TestComponentBuilder and ComponentFixture is now in @angular/core/testing,
- beforeEachProviders:

code:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [MyService]);
```

changed to:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([MyService]);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I got this also, but do you know how to migrate the test to RC5, because after reading their release notes I still don't get how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If you already read their release note. It's a lot of change in testing API package.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

So, I didn't try to migrate test to RC5 yet. But I found link about change to new testing API.

[https://ng2-info.github.io/2016/08/angular-2-rc-5/#テスティングapiに関する変更](https://ng2-info.github.io/2016/08/angular-2-rc-5/#%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0api%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4)

Hope this help.